# Reinitialising an Ember application/restoring application state

Tags: javascript, ember.js, seo

I'm rendering a static HTML page with phantom.js for SEO purposes inside a Node.JS backend according to Google's AJAX crawling specification (`?_escaped_fragment_=...`). The front-end application is written in Ember (version `1.0.0`).

I noticed while testing those static HTML URLs inside my browser that Ember cannot be re-initialised, leading to errors like

```
Assertion failed: You cannot use the same root element (body) multiple times in an    Ember.Application 
Assertion failed: You cannot make a new Ember.Application using a root element that is a descendent of an existing Ember.Application
```

I was wondering if:

- those errors occur because the DOM is already populated with Ember's HTML classes and IDs?
  For example: `<body class="ember-application">` or `<script id="metamorph-7-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>`
- there is a way to re-initialise my Ember application with the already pre-rendered DOM without any errors and without having to modify HTML classes with some regular expression magic before I deliver them through my Node.js back-end?
- I even could restore the application state of my Ember app?

Answer (score 2):

You receive this error because you are declaring more than one ember app, in the same [rootElement](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html#property_rootElement):

```
// ok
App = Ember.Application.create({ rootElement: "#wizard" });
/// rootElement default to "body"
App = Ember.Application.create();
// throw error. we already have a ember app with rootElement equals to "body"
App = Ember.Application.create();
```

To reinitialize the app you can use the [reset](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html#method_reset) method:

```
App.reset();
```